# Ubuntu for phones - cannot find any Carrier

Tags: ubuntu-touch, galaxy-nexus

I already installed Ubuntu for phones in my Galaxy Nexus. Looks perfect but I am not able connect my phone to any carrier. When I want to choose one manually, it shows only `searching` all the time [now about 30 min.]

I used this Ubuntu [Touch wiki tutorial](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Touch/Install).

I am a newbie in this area so please for little help. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

from: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Touch/ReleaseNotes (dated 2013-07-28)

> **Telephony**
>
> The Developer Preview currently only supports limited voice and SMS over GSM and WCDMA.
>
> The following Radio technologies are not yet included in the Developer Preview:
>
> > CDMA
> >
> > LTE
> >
> > Airplane Mode
> >
> > Settings ( eg. APN choice, 2G only, … )

---

I also suggest reading the ***ubuntu-phone team mailing list archive***

https://lists.launchpad.net/ubuntu-phone/maillist.html