# Galaxy Nexus 4 Ubuntu Touch CDMA Questions

Tags: ubuntu-touch, cdma, nexus-4

I was considering getting a Galaxy Nexus 4 and flashing ubuntu touch to start playing with it. Couple of questions:

- does ubuntu touch work yet with CDMA?
- Will sudo apt-get dist-upgrade & upgrade work from the terminal and will that enable me to update ubuntu without having to keep reflashing the phone as ubuntu touch moves forward in development?
- My old galaxy nexus nexus has a 4g sim card. Are there any advantages to that when I get my new galaxy nexus 4?
- Will python 3 be on the ubuntu touch by default and can apps be developed with phython as they already can with any other ubuntu installation?
- Does nexus 4 "mako" work on CDMA or is that a GSM thing?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! It is preferred if you can post separate questions instead of combining your questions into one. That way, it helps the people answering your question and also others hunting for atleast one of your questions. Thanks!

Comment: Questions 1 & 5 (about CDMA), duplicate of: http://askubuntu.com/questions/327483/ubuntu-for-phones-cannot-find-any-carrier

Comment: Question 2: refer to Wiki page.

Answer (score 0):

I've recently been researching the Ubuntu Touch operating system and have stumbled upon answers to all your questions.

First: `"does ubuntu touch work yet with CDMA?"`

Well this is an interesting question that I was wondering myself as I am a Verizon user and the answer is quite simply, No. On a post by Ricardo Salveti, Tony Espy who is an employee at the company which owns Ubuntu made a comment in which he stated,

> There is currently no support for CDMA devices in Touch, and it's not
>   on our current roadmap.
>
> That said merge proposals are always welcome if someone in the
>   community wants to take this on...

This shooting down our hopes, yet the post this comment was upon detailed how to enable 3G data, but the method may not work on CDMA. (I will test this myself when I get a Galaxy Nexus using CDMA code named toro)

Second: `updates from terminal`

I have found that currently there is a way to updating without reflashing. On the wikipedia page for Ubuntu Touch, there is a field labeled **Update method** which reads "Click Update Manager, Image Based Updates" and I have found that others say command line works just as well.

Third: `sdcard`

You must understand that the Galaxy Nexus and Nexus 4 are two different devices. Neither of which have an SD card slot.

Fourth: `python3`

The Ubuntu Touch operating system is a full operating system with a codebase similar to Ubuntu which means the Debian APT system is implemented, yet it is not identical as it does not use Xorg and runs on an ARM processor. These facts as well as the launchpad page for python3 show that it is available on the mobile operating system.

Fifth: `mako`

The Nexus 4 code named mako only shipped with GSM compatibility. The Galaxy Nexus is sold for both GSM and CDMA. The Galaxy Nexus for CDMA was code named toro for Verizon and toroplus for Sprint. Yet Ubuntu Touch is said to be released in April of 2014, this year. This fact gives me hope that CDMA support may be developed in the coming months.

Conclusion:

This question was answered for the purpose of those researching Ubuntu Touch OS and Serves not for helping you chose what to buy seeing as its been so ling since you posted this, but as a reference.

Sources:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galaxy_Nexus

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nexus_4

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_Phone

https://plus.google.com/u/0/+RicardoSalveti/posts/3o1tjYo9Ghx

[How to update my already installed Ubuntu Touch image?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/358741/how-to-update-my-already-installed-ubuntu-touch-image)