# How to update my already installed Ubuntu Touch image?

Tags: updates, ubuntu-touch

I noticed today that when I opened the update manager through the system settings in Ubuntu touch running on Nexus 7, it showed no updates. But the I ran the following two commands in the terminal:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

Certain updates started getting downloaded, and upon my consent, they were installed.

Why is this so? Why doesn't the over the air updates facility show the updates? I am running the latest daily build image of Ubuntu touch.

Comment: The correct **3** commands are: **`sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade`**, followed by **`sudo apt-get dist-upgrade`**. You should also first use (once): **`sudo add-apt-repository ppa:phablet-team/ppa`**. *That said, the OTA updates are intended to support a (R/O) image.*

Comment: Will that update my ubuntu touch to the latest daily build image??

Comment: It should, but with *beta code* you will still need to do a full refresh (**`-b`**) every few weeks. Some of the underlying code may cause problems, with changes to interfaces (to underlying ROM or Android) or UI architecture.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Updating through the system settings will do an image upgrade which only works when the image is not in *writable image* mode.

This rather different than doing a package update through apt-get.

These two mechanisms are mutually exclusive:

- Image Based Upgrades work on non writable images (read only filesystem)
- Apt get works on writable images

Once on writable image mode the way to get back is to reflash the system (not necessarily losing your user data).

```
adb shell rm /userdata/.writable_image
ubuntu-device-flash [--channel channel_name]
```

Details on image based upgrades can be read further here: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/ImageBasedUpgrades

There is a third possibility and that's the one that you may have installed a cdimage based image which is writable by default and today is considered an intermediate image to get to the system images.

Answer (score 1):

For those who stumble upon this question looking for support for Ubuntu Touch. Canonical  stopped support for Ubuntu Touch on 5 April 2017. The project was taken over by UBports as a community project. You can install and maintain Ubuntu Touch on their website [Ubuntu Touch](https://ubuntu-touch.io/)