# How to upgrade Ubuntu touch on Nexus 5

Tags: ubuntu-touch, nexus-5x

I have recently installed Ubuntu touch 15.04 on my Nexus 5 following this guide
https://2buntu.com/articles/1489/installing-ubuntu-touch-on-a-nexus-5/
My scope does not work, from anything from calculator to browser.

I figure that because this guide is 2years old the New 'yakkety yak 16.10' is the more stable build.

Seeing as I can not run even terminal on my Nexus nor boot into the Bootloader I am a bit stuck with not much to go on.

Does anyone know a guide to follow or a process for Nexus 5 to upgrade. The software on my nexus says its up to date when going into the settings on ubuntu touch.

This guide here is the only one i can find with promise but seeing as I cant open terminal.. [How to update my already installed Ubuntu Touch image?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/358741/how-to-update-my-already-installed-ubuntu-touch-image)

Look forward to any replies

Comment: Why can't you just boot recovery and flash a newer rom? Here is the  way https://www.google.co.uk/?client=ubuntu#channel=fs&q=nexus+5+recovery&gfe_rd=cr or with adb issue `reboot-recovery` I think.

Comment: Ok i was able to get to Bootloader then to Ubuntu Recovery. However there is no option for flashing. Do you know your way round? I will do some research myself and post if I find anything before you

Comment: I don't have this device but you must of used something like twrp or cwm to flash the rom right? Use this to flash a later version.

Comment: I used twrp and I can not get back there. I can get back to the bootloader and thats it. Now I will try to transfer over twrp via adb to my nexus... somehow

Answer (score 0):

adb didn't work for me in the respect that NO device was listed when typing in terminal 'adb devices'

small workaround was to -

Open the folder where your TWRP Recovery .img file is saved.
Then open a CMD window inside that folder. To do that, Shift + Right click on any empty white space inside the folder and then select Open command window here or simply right click and select 'open terminal here'.
Connect your Android device to the PC. Type the following into the command window to boot your device into bootloader/fastboot mode:

adb reboot bootloader

└ If your asks for permission to “Allow USB debugging”, tap OK.
Once your device boots into bootloader mode, type this into the command line.

fastboot flash recovery twrp-2.8.x.x-xxx.img

└ Here modify twrp.img with the name of your TWRP recovery .img file.

Then you can flash any file in TWRP using its bootloader recovery.

The other option is to go to the stock bootloader then follow this simple basic guide https://devices.ubports.com/#/hammerhead just for nexus.

All my problems went away, wifi didnt work then I just reset the phone and works well.